# Building APIs with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need help here. I created a model in my Django-rest-framework. I have added rest_framework in the `settings.py`. I have migrated and done all the `makemigrations` command prompt. The model still does not show up in my admin panel

This is installed apps part in my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'myapi.apps.MyapiConfig',
'rest_framework',
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial explains that very well. I'm not going to copy/paste it but here is the link:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#introducing-the-django-admin

You have to create an admin.py file in your app's folder and register the models you want in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

you should register that model in admin.py

Comment: admin.site.register(your model)

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60455988/edit) link to update or add information on your answer. Don't put it in the comments.